# battery indicator for android

Tags: android, power-management

I have the following sample code for indicating the battery level. When I run the code it gives me a force close error. Anyone has any idea why?

```
public class ActActivity extends Activity {


      private BroadcastReceiver _batteryinfo = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int iBatLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
                /*ProgressBar _batPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                _batPB.setProgress(iBatLevel);
                TextView _batText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.batterylevel);
                _batText.setText("Battery level:"+Integer.toString(iBatLevel)+"%");
                */
                Toast.makeText(context, iBatLevel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        registerReceiver(_batteryinfo, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

}
```

I have the following in my manifest file though I read somewhere it's not needed for dynamic receiver creation.

```
<receiver android:name=".service.BatteryActivity">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: To summarize from comments in the answers: The code here works perfectly fine; the force close was caused by a TextView without an ID, something entirely unrelated to anything in this question. I don't think this question offers anything of value to future visitors; voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver,new      
   IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

and

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()  {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {          
          int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);      
      } 
}
```

Comment: this will work,  i am using this code in my app. working perfectly. add this code in onCreate() methid.

Answer (score 0):

check this link i think you need to add a permission in menifest
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BATTERY_STATS

public static final String BATTERY_STATS
Since: API Level 1

Allows an application to collect battery statistics
Constant Value: "android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"

also
Inside onReceive, retrieve data based on the "level" item (battery level) for version < 5, or use BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL for versions >= 5.

Comment: In menifest after application tag is closed </application> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />     </application>
        
</manifest>

Comment: correction :  permissions should be before application tag. and even after adding this permission i still get the force close error!!!

Comment: it can be both the ways , anyhow can you put your logcat also

Comment: it worked!!! even without adding the permission!!! mistake was in my xml file where i didnt have id for my textview :/ sorry for the disturbance.....